# Is there a pretty print API for a mathematical String somewhere?

Tags: java

Is there a pretty print API for a mathematical String somewhere?

For example:

"10000000 - 234564"

Becomes

"10,000,000 minus 234,564"

I can make my own but can someone give me some pointers on how to do the "," part?

Comment: How is writing “minus” instead of “–” == pretty-printed?!

Comment: oh, this is because I am using a text to speech engine and when I use "-" is says "to" not "minus"

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better name for that than "pretty printing". I don't know what it is, however.

Comment: @Joachim: pretty reading? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
  DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) f;
  df.setGroupingUsed(true);
  df.setGroupingSize(3);
  System.out.println(df.format(myNumber));
}
```

Comment: why do you need the "if" condition?

Comment: @jax, I took the example from the Javadoc I linked. Now that I think of it, I realize that in your case you can probably create a DecimalFormat directly.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to "," formatting (I guess you mean the thousands separator) NumberFormat is your friend. More specifically I guess you would want to use its subclass [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), which can format a number according to given pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The "," part can be done using the "," Flag of the [Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) used by e.g. String.format. It's called the [Grouping Separator](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getGroupingSeparator()).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.out.format("%," n);
```

Where `n` — is your extracted int. For more options (like using `DecimalFormat` class) read [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).